# Please help identify characters in my seal on a modern brush painting

Tags: meaning, characters, seal

[image]I am trying to find information on the characters in the red seal in the lower right corner of a painting.It is on paper and seems modern. I suppose it is a signature, Thanks for any information

Answer (score 1):

The seal read 李麟 /Lǐ lín/, It is a name of a person

李 means 'plum' (family name)

麟 as in 麒麟 (Kirin)

*麒麟 is one of the four spirit beasts in Chinese myth (the others are 1.dragon  2.phoenix and 4.tortoise)*

[image]

Note:

Google Translate translates 麒 as 'mythical unicorn'; 麟 as 'female unicorn' Which mean 麒麟 is the general term for 'mythical unicorn', but the image of 麒麟 in Chinese culture is quite different from the unicorn in the western myth which we call 獨角獸 (one-horned beast)

[image]

Comment: Lee is more difficult to be connected to the modern form.

Comment: Thank you for this info Tang Ho, I may assume this was just a local artist who made this painting....

Comment: @Karen I searched the web and found a painter named 李麟 (1558—？) in the Ming Dynasty. Most likely not the same 李麟 unless the painting you have is over 400 years old

Comment: Tang Ho, wouldn't that be nice!  I don't think its old...not a great framing job...I may take it out and look at it more closely

Comment: I found a contemporary artist with the name Li Lin, she does sumi type brush paintings, mine is of bamboo tree leaves, it looks similar